# Kind of minified component names in Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on an angular project, which shows a strange behaviour. Unfortunately I don't know what causes this or when it happened.
The problem is, that in the browser dev tools the source names are kind of minified. There are only two components. These are **e** and **t**. This makes debugging very painful

In environments.ts the production mode is set to false. And the console log "Angular is running in development mode" prooves this. The Chrome Plugin "Augury" isn't complaining either (so it's noticed as an Angular app)

```
//main.ts:

if (environment.production) {
enableProdMode();
}

//environment.ts:

export const environment = {
production: false,
envName: 'dev'
};
```

I attached some screenhots of the Chrome Dev Tools. I hope you can help me to bring back the real source names.

kind regards
Parg

[image]
[image]

Comment: How are you running the server

Comment: I'm running it with Glassfish and Payara. 
But even if I start the project without backend (ng start) it shows the same problem

Comment: You mean to say ng serve ?

Comment: yes, ng serve. sorry :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly after creating this question I stumbled upon the answer myself, sorry for bothering you.

The maven build configuration in pom.xml had **--prod** as argument. I changed it to **--dev**.